# Как оставить центр изображения в середине при разных размерах адаптивной вёрстки

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

У меня на десктопе стоит фоном изображение, а на нём лежит текст. Возможно ли сделать так чтобы при различных размерах адаптивной вёрстки, оно полностью оставалось центрированным изначального размера, а края у него заходили за окно браузера?

Буду очень благодарен!

Comment: `background-size: cover` поможет

Answer (score 0):

Используйте свойство CSS

```
background-position: center;
```